# ERROR Error: Requiring unknown module "undefined"

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

When I try to use @react-navigation/bottom-tabs the following error appears:

```
Error: Requiring unknown module "undefined". If you are sure the module exists, try restarting Metro. You may also want to run `yarn` or `npm install`.
MaterialBottomTabView@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.goout&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:126353:43
MaterialBottomTabNavigator@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.goout&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:126107:32
BottomTabNavigator
EnsureSingleNavigator@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.goout&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:109377:24
BaseNavigationContainer@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.goout&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:108889:28
ThemeProvider@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.goout&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:114532:21
NavigationContainerInner@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.goout&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:114392:26
App
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
AppContainer@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.goout&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:75604:36
goout(RootComponent)@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.goout&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:82460:28
```

package.json

```js
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.0.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.7",
    "fbjs": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.65.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.1",
    "undefined": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/": "react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.65.0",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.14",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
```

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {Home} from './Pages/places/Home';
import {Details} from './Pages/places/details';

import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const {Navigator, Screen} = createBottomTabNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Navigator>
        <Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
      </Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I already try remove node_modules. I tried use Material Bottom Tab but i get the same error.

edit 1

> ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[6], "@react-navigation/elements").ResourceSavingView')

This error message appears below the first message.

Answer (score 9):

I had same issue and just fixed after installing react-native-screens

```
yarn add react-native-screens
```

or

```
npm install react-native-screens
```

Comment: This just worked for me as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Run this
`rm -rf ./node_modules`
then
`yarn` or `npm i`

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

When you are working with react navigation. Please make sure this

***The libraries we will install now are react-native-screens and react-native-safe-area-context.***

The lacking of them will causing some unknown error like above yours.So follow these steps:

- Run command: `yarn add react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context`
- Build the app again for making native libraries be launched to the app. For iOS using command `cd ios && pod install` and Installing app again to Emulator.

That's it CHEER!

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart the bundle and re-run the react-native run  after installing react-navigation bottom tabs? React Navigation does have some native code and as such needs a rebuild on the device after installing the module.

Comment: yes, i did that but the error persist.

Comment: Have you tried not spreading the result of createBottomTabNavigator? I know it sounds stupid but it's worth a try.

Comment: didn't solve either =(

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. you have a module named "undefined" in your package.json. right under styled components.

Comment: I installed this package after the error appeared, now i removed it and remains the same =/

Comment: Is this index.tsx file in the root of your project? Like does it replace your index.js file where you register the app? Or does that exist as well and you register the app there?

Comment: The both files exists, index.tsx is inside src and is imported in index.js that is located in root

Answer (score 0):

run below command

```
npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

and then for ios pod install

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also when I upgraded all my dependencies and React Native.
So I went through the documentation of React Navigation, they suggest to install `react-native-screens` and `react-native-safe-area-context`

```
yarn add react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

Here is the link to the documentation

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

npm install react-native-screens
npm start -- --reset-cache
worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Try installing react-native-vector-icons. It helped me.